# Erro ao tentar logar no localhost pelo PhpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Estou tentando conectar na minha database local e estou recebendo os seguintes erros:

1. > #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'187.20.253.86' (using password: NO)
2. > mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'187.20.253.86' (using password: NO)

Acredito que seja porque ele está tentando se conectar á `187.20.253.86` e não ao `localhost`, mas mesmo se o problema for esse, não sei como resolver.

Estou utilizando o *WampServer 3.0.6*.

Comment: Servidor local?

Comment: Sim, é um servidor local.

Comment: Mas se é local porque está usando ip externo pra conectar?

Comment: Não sei ;-; Eu baixei o Wamp e ele veio assim...

Comment: Alguma ideia de como voltar para o `localhost`? @Articuno

Comment: Como está o arquivo `config.inc.php`?

Comment: Consegui, eu estava olhando o `config.sample.inc.php` ao invés do `config.inc.php` kkkk

Comment: Vou fazer uma resposta para ajudar outras pessoas que tiverem o mesmo problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Procure pelo arquivo `config.inc.php` que provavelmente deve estar em `C:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin4.6.4` e abra-o com algum editor de texto.

Obs: Cuidado para não confundir com algum arquivo chamado `config.sample.inc.php`!

Procure pela linha com esses argumentos:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '/*OUTRO IP*/';
```

E troque o valor para `localhost`:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

Answer (score 0):

isso não é erro de localização da base e sim de acesso, "acesso negado para usuario root", tente entrar passando usúario em branco ou "admin", depois tente entrar passando uma senha(password), normalmente, senha padrão é root ou admin também. Espero ter ajudado